# html-list links doesn't work

Tags: html, css, html-lists

For some reason my nav list is not clickable (links won't work), and whichever properties I type into the #languagenav class (i.e. text-align: center) it doesn't show any result. What am I doing wrong?

Link to site: http://bit.ly/VSSoul

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
        <div class="languagenav">
            <ul class="languagenav">
                <li>English - Spanish</li>
                <li><a href"./booksdictengger.html">English - German</a></li>
                <li><a href"./booksdictengfre.html">English - French</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.languagenav li {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 1em;
    font-size: 15pt;
    font-family: 'Dosis', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #25271e;
}

.languagenav a {
    color: #6d0839; 
    text-decoration: none;
}

#languagenav {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Also while we're at it. For each book the text centers relative to the image, how do I make the text align to the top of the image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a `=`. Without this you have invalid HTML.

```
<a href"./booksdictengger.html">
```

Should be:

```
<a href="./booksdictengger.html">
```

---

Regarding the center alignment issue, your CSS rule is `#languagenav` when it should be `.languagenav`

Comment: I think I just blushed. Thank you! Any idea why centering via #languagenav won't work?

Comment: @user1736049 You have `#languagenav`, but no elements that use that ID (they're using classes).

Comment: I'm pretty sure centering a inline ul does work, as that is what I've done on the main navigation (#nav). using margins on ul did work though, thank you. @cimmanon thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an equals sign in the `a` tag: `<a href=".`

Answer (score -1):

Try it like this:

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="languagenav">
        <ul class="languagenav">
            <li>English - Spanish</li>
            <li><a href="/booksdictengger.html">English - German</a></li>
            <li><a href="/booksdictengfre.html">English - French</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

LE : The correct syntax for an anchor is:

```
<a href="#"></a>
```

not:

```
<a href""></a>
```

You forgot the equal sign.

Comment: Code is nice, but it would be nicer if you pointed out why yours works and his doesn't.